# How to convert an array to a double so big array?

Tags: c#

I have an element type:

```
public class FieldInfo
{
  public string Label { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an array filled with `FieldInfo` objects.

```
FieldInfo[] infos = new FieldInfo[]
                      {
                        new FieldInfo{Label = "label1", Value = "value1"},
                        new FieldInfo{Label = "label2", Value = "value2"}
                      };
```

Now I want to convert that array to a new one that contains following values:

```
string[] wantThatArray = new string[] {"label1", "value1", "label2", "value2"};
```

Is there a short way to do the conversion from an array like `infos` to an array like `wantThatArray`?
Maybe with LINQ's Select?

Comment: just a heads-up: calling a class `FieldInfo` may cause a *lot* of confusion if you go near reflection. Also - your object initializer is not valid - `new FieldInfo{"label1","value1"}` is not legal C#

Comment: Thanks Marc. The real name of my class is `InputFieldInfo`. I have shorten my example.

Comment: Now that you have an answer have you looked into maybe using a Struct instead of creating a whole new class like that?

Comment: I have fixed the object initializer issue.

Comment: @jvanh1 I'm not sure that is good advice; it *could* make a sensible struct, it if was made immutable etc, but: the decision isn't as simple as just "is it smallish"

Comment: @Marc Gravell I agree, thus why I said think about maybe using a struct, I don't know enough about what he plans on using that particular segment for to properly establish whether a struct would be appropriate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string[] wantThatArray = infos
    .SelectMany(f => new[] {f.Label, f.Value})
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: It should be noted that this creates a lot of additional arrays etc in the middle, and creates a lot of intermediate enumerators etc - it is a lot of overhead to achieve something simple.

Comment: +1 this does the job in Linq but I'd still stick with the for loop

Comment: I like them both for separate reasons, Marc definitely wins for efficiency, but this one is much more elegant.

Comment: @MarcGravell, absolutely right. It is the same old question "elegance and readability vs performance". Each solution can be a better choice in a particular situation.

Comment: @Andrei I have needed some time to understand `SelectMany`. But this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 8):

I would keep it simple:

```
string[] wantThatArray = new string[infos.Length * 2];
for(int i = 0 ; i < infos.Length ; i++) {
   wantThatArray[i*2] = infos[i].Label;
   wantThatArray[i*2 + 1] = infos[i].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different variant to Marc Gravell's solution

```
string[] wantThatArray = new string[infos.Length * 2];
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < infos.Length; i++, k += 2) {
   wantThatArray[k] = infos[i].Label;
   wantThatArray[k + 1] = infos[i].Value;
}
```

Comment: Nice; you could also lose the `k+=2`, and have `[k++]` in both lines in the loop body

Comment: Yes but since `k` is initialized in the for-part, it is more logical to increment it there too. It makes the statement more symmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

another variant:

```
string[] yourarray = infos.Select(x => string.Format("{0},{1}", x.Label, x.Value))
                          .Aggregate((x, y) => string.Format("{0},{1}", x, y))
                          .Split(',');
```

mhh but not nice.. :( compared to the others !

Comment: Then I have an array `new string[] {"label1,value1", "label2,value2"};`. This is different to that I want, or do I miss something.

Comment: Ohh but yes , I missed it completely .. then I would have to use aggregate,  and split by ','... not so nice isn't it.. sorry for the bad answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
FieldInfo[,] infos = new FieldInfo[,]{
                    new FieldInfo{"label1", "value1"},
                    new FieldInfo{"label2", "value2"}
                  };

string[] to = infos.Cast<FieldInfo>().ToArray();
```

Now you can simply convert `to` to `infos`.

Comment: See the edit to the question; the `infos` object is not a 2-d array.